# Spring databinding tag form not necessary?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, data-binding

I'm studying databinding in Spring MVC and I was approaching the use of tag form to implement it. As it is described, it seems to be necessary in order to implement databinding in Spring framework.

But I made a test with Spring Boot, and I didn't use the form tag, and even the JSP page for input, but just an external HTML page.

So, the question is, the form tag is useful but not necessary, or it's not necessary only with Spring Boot?

The code below. Thanks!

input HTML form

```
<html>
<body>
<h3> Registration Form <h3>
<br/>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/register" method="post" >
    <pre>
         Name <input type="text" name="name" />
         Email address <input type="text" name="emailAddress" />
         Password <input type="password" name="password" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </pre>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring controller:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public String greeting(User user, Model model) {  
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.bytecode</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootBindingForm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Output page with Thymeleaf (in order to verify correct databinding)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Name, ' + ${user.name} + '!'" />
    <p th:text="'Password, ' + ${user.password} + '!'" />
    <p th:text="'Email, ' + ${user.emailAddress} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

And **User.java** and **Application.java** that I don't think it's necessary to show here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tag form gives some adding functionalities, but it's not strictly necessary to implement Spring Controller Databinding.

Otherwise it would be impossible to implement DataBinding using a simple HTML form or PostMan without sending the request from a JSP with that specific tag.